# postgres schema grants usage

Tags: postgresql, permissions, schema

I have a database called layers. in it there are two schemas 1. how 2. base_layers

each schema has its own login name and password and both are not superusers. I want the ability to query across both schemas from within the schema logins(not using postgres superuser)

[image]

above I am running this query from the base_layers schema login and it gives me this permission denied error. if i run this query through the postgres connection it works... what is the proper way to be granting usage from schema to schema without making each login name a superuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They already have access to each others schemas.  That is what the 'no privileges granted' warning is about, they already had them.

But being able to access a schema doesn't give you access to the objects within the schema.  You would need something like:

```
grant select on all tables in schema how to base_layers;
```

And to accommodate tables created in the future:

```
alter default PRIVILEGES for user how in schema how grant select on tables to base_layers;
```

Also, you should probably revoke CREATE on each schema from the cross-schema user, it sounds like you just want USAGE.

Comment: I want full pretty much full everything from one schema to another without making it a superuser... what would be the command for that?

Comment: okay this worked - but to learn from this when setting up a database with multiple schemas and logins is there a default option that will allow a login on a schema to have access on another schema with create and select privileges?

Comment: also how would I reverse this command to revoke access?

Answer (score 0):

With a super-user, do a one-time GRANT to both logins and add `WITH GRANT OPTION` to the end. It sounds like the users have the ability to query their own schemas but are not allowed to grant it to others.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html